# How to handle two solidity events with asyncio python

Tags: python, brownie, swaps, async, event-handling

Im trying to get every Swap event happens on Uniswap and Sushiswap using python and do stuff based on these Swaps i know how to do it but with one exchange, it means that only one event in time .

```
from brownie import interface, accounts
import asyncio

def main():

    event_filter = uniswap_pair.events.Swap.createFilter(fromBlock="latest")
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                log_loop(event_filter, 2)
            )
        )
    finally:
        loop.close()


def handle_event(event):
    print(Web3.toJSON(event))


async def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for Swap in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(Swap)
        await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)
```

how can i change my code so it can handle also sushiswap events simultaneously ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another coroutine loop to `asyncio.gather` call, this way they would execute in parallel. Like that:

```
    uniswap_event_filter = uniswap_pair.events.Swap.createFilter(fromBlock="latest")
    
    sushiswap_event_filter = sushiswap_pair.events.Swap.createFilter(fromBlock="latest")
    


    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                log_loop(uniswap_event_filter, 2),
                log_loop(sushiswap_event_filter, 2),
            )
        )
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Your handler is sync, though, so you won't really get any performance improvement. I assume it's just for the example. I also assume that your code works and you init those uniswap_pair (and therefore can init sushiswap_pair) somewhere.